# Monotonicity of $\neg\neg$

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

We live in a topos. Given $x\in X$ write $\neg\neg \left\{ x \right\}$ for the subobject comprised of $x^\prime \in X$ satisfying $\neg\neg(x=x^\prime)$, i.e $x,x^\prime$ are indistinguishable. In (1.6) of [this paper by Bunge](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404983900713), we have the following.

**Claim.** Let $x\in X$ and let $x^\prime\in \neg\neg \left\{x \right\}$. Let $f:\neg\neg \left\{ x \right\}\to Y$. Then $fx^\prime \in \neg\neg \left\{ fx \right\}$.

The proof:

> This holds on account of the monotonicity of $\neg\neg$.

This is probably super basic, but what is meant by the monotonicity of $\neg\neg$, and why is $\neg\neg$ monotonic in this sense? I'm guessing this has something to do with Lawvere-Tierney topologies, but I don't really know anything about them.

Comment: What is $X$? ${}{}{}$. What does this have to do with $R$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews whoops! You're right of course. I wrote $R$ but then slightly modified the contents of the linked paper. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Monotonicity of $\lnot\lnot$" means that if $X \to Y$ is provable then so is $\lnot\lnot X \to \lnot\lnot Y$ (in the intuitionistic language of the toposes in question). This isn't too hard to see, e.g., using the provable assertion $(X \to Y) \to (\lnot Y \to \lnot X)$.